# No params on DataTable server rendering

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTables server rendering to show thousand of data in a view with this script:

```js
$('#info-comisiones').DataTable({

   "processing": true,
   "serverside": true,
   ajax: {
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Sales/GetSalesByPaymentPeriodID",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     data: function (dtParms) {
       console.log(dtParms);
       return JSON.stringify(dtParms);
     },
     dataFilter: function (res) {
       var parsed = JSON.parse(res);
       return JSON.stringify(parsed.d);
     },
     error: function (x, y) {
       console.log(x);
     }
   },
   "filter": true,
   columns: [
     {"data":"#"},
     {"data":"F.Registro"},
     {"data":"Hora"},
     {"data":"Confirmación"},
     {"data":"Habitación"},
     {"data":"# Colaborador"},
     {"data":"Nombre Colaborador"},
     {"data":"Puesto"},
     {"data":"Centro Consumo"},
     {"data":"Misceláneo"},
     {"data":"Capturista"},
     {"data":"Puesto C."},
     {"data":"Fecha Salida"},
     {"data":"Descripción"},
     {"data":"Moneda"},
     {"data":"Acciones"},
     {"data":"Cantidad"},
     {"data":"T.Cambio"},
     {"data":"% Descuento"},
     {"data":"Impuestos"},
     {"data":"Precio Unitario MXN"},
     {"data":"Precio Unitario USD"},
     {"data":"Total Neto"},
     {"data":"% Comsión"},
     {"data":"Total Comision MXN"}
   ]
});
```

But the issue here is that in the line where I'm trying to see the data that is being sent to the server: `console.log(dtParms);` is showing an empty JSON object, and the server side is not receiving any data.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some notes. I think item (1) may be the only problem, but I mention the others, just in case they are also useful.

---

1. The `dataFilter` function in your Ajax call - why do you need that?

It throws away the response and only keeps `parsed.d`. I don't know what `parsed.d` is supposed to be - but it's probably empty or invalid.

You need to keep all of the response as it contains (or it *should* contain) all of the data needed by DataTables. That is not only the actual table data but also related metadata as described in the [Returned Data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) section of the Server-Side manual.

I think you need to remove that `dataFilter` piece completely.

And make sure the response from the server matches the [expected JSON response structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data).

---

2. What is `"filter": true`? That is not a valid DataTables option. It won't cause any harm. It will just be ignored.

---

3. The table's `columns` settings. This may not actually be a problem, but it looks very unusual. You have column settings such as this:

   {"data":"Nombre Colaborador"}

The value `Nombre Colaborador` should be a key in the `data` section of the JSON response - and maybe it is. But it's more typical to see JSON keys such as `nombreColaborador` instead. Like I say, maybe this is OK.

I mention this because the JSON keys are usually generated from your server-side data model structures, where the fields you are using do not permit spaces in their names.

---

It's possible that there may be more (or different) issues not shown in the question, and not covered in my answer. If so, then you may need to add a sample of your JSON to the question.